# Height different in IE FF Chrome

Tags: html, css, scroll, height

Good day, after struggling with a problem at my previous post, i entered another problem caused by different heights in web crossing.

Example: http://www.sushitaksteeg.nl/secret/template.html

Download: http://www.sushitaksteeg.nl/secret/Port.rar

If you press on the scroll page button, the page scrolls perfectly in FF but not in Chrome and IE.

I did this by setting the next property in styles.css:

<-- #footer{height:870px;} -->

Again i have searched google and stackoverflow, and tried CSS reset, but didn't work..

Someone any ideas?

*EDIT*

Mike helped me out with parent.scroll(), it's better now but still I can see a white line between the header and footer in FF and Chrome, IE is showing it good now.

Any more help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: i get the same behaviour in chrome 11.0.696.65 and ff 4.0.1 (page scrolls to bottom). IE 8 behaves differently (the page doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page. but stops when the two images meet). What behaviour is it that you want?

Comment: I want it to look like how it looks now on IE: open with IE http://www.sushitaksteeg.nl/secret/template.html

In FF and Chrome you can see a white line between the header and footer, i want them to look like in IE. Any ideas?

ps. i am using chrome 10.0.648.205, ie 8.0.7601.17514, FF newest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your JavaScript is using window.scrollBy(). In Chrome/IE, scrolling can be done with parent.scroll().

Comment: when i replace windows.scrollBy() with parent.scroll(), it does nothing on Chrome, IE and FF.

*edit*

i have uploaded the updated version now. It is way better now, but still in FF and chrome it's not looking so good, you can see a white line in between the images. Can you also provide me information about that? 

parent.scroll() is way better than window.scrollBy() thank you

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem lies. It scrolls perfectly fine for me. The only difference is that IE has a smaller visible vertical client than Chrome so when Chrome attempts to scroll down to 95, it hits the bottom of the page so it can not scroll 95 pixels. If I make the Chrome window smaller it scrolls just fine. It also works perfectly in Firefox as well.

Comment: thank you for your help! it helped me out :D it works now and also thanks to Jules :D

Answer (score 1):

To solve your second problem (with the white line):

remove the `<br>` tags inside your `<div id="content"></div>` and add a height of 38px to your content div, so in your css file you get:

```
#content {
  height: 38px;
}
```

is that what you wanted? The problem was that the content-div scaled with the data in it. You tried to get the right height using br-tags, but those don't have a standard height and depend on what browser you are using. Specifying the height in css will make it the same height in all browsers (as long as the content fits in it, else it will scale (unsless you also specify the css property `overflow: hidden;` for the content-div)).

Comment: Great it worked for IE and FF! Thank you, but in Chrome the header and footer does not fit together. What to do there?

Comment: @F4LLCON Works fine in my version of chrome (11) Don't have version 10 to test, so I'm not sure. Only thing I can think of is maybe chrome cached the page on your computer. Try ctrl+F5 and verify the css is loaded correctly..

Comment: that is really strange, i have installed the new chrome and still it shows bad. I also ctrl + f5 and nothing. 

* EDIT * 

@Jules Thank you! i have deleted everything with Ccleaner, and now it just works! Like you say, the cache was not good... Thank you Jules! :)